# Change PHP Time

Tags: php, mysql

I would like some help to add 5 hours to my server hours, I can't access the php.ini file.

for example im getting the time in mysql like this `2016-12-21 13:57:54` but in my country is `2016-12-21 18:57:54`, I need to add five hours to to time, I saw some functions like this one:

```
 $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$today = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H", strtotime("$today + 5 hours"));
```

But it's not working im not getting the minutes it's allways 18:00:00 or 19:00.00.

Comment: You may want to check out changing the timezone in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Also, if you are using `strftime()`, you need to be calling `setlocale()` first since that function depends on the locale. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-examples

Comment: `%Y-%m-%d-%H` - also you have conversion only to format date + hours (without minutes and seconds)

you should use `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` instead to get a minutes and seconds too

Comment: Use `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time is always in UTC, so you can format it like this:

`date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");
 echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s');`

You can change the format to whatever you need, and replace the `date_default_timezone_set` parameter with your current location.

See **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/H7nW3B)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime($today, $tz);
$date->modify('+5 hours');
```

**or**

`$date = date('h:i:s A', time()+18000);` // time() returns a time in seconds already & 5 hours = 18000 seconds.